# Usage of runRVar over some monad transformer stack

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

In the following example:

```
toss :: Double -> RVar Bool
toss p = do
  q <- uniform 0 1
  return $ q <= p

toss' :: MonadRandom m => Double -> m Bool
toss' p = runRVar (toss p) StdRandom


foo :: StateT Int RVar ()
foo = do
    h <- lift $ toss' 0.5
    if h then put 100 else put 0

bar :: StateT Int RVar ()
bar = do
    h <- lift $ toss 0.5
    if h then put 404 else put 200


testFoo :: MonadRandom m => m ((), Int)
testFoo = runRVar (runStateT foo 0) StdRandom

testBar :: MonadRandom m => m ((), Int)
testBar = runRVar (runStateT bar 0) StdRandom
```

I am confused about:

1. why the signature of foo is forced to be `StateT Int RVar ()` even though `toss'` has signature `m Bool` for some `MonadRandom m`
2. Why `testFoo` has to be run with some `StdRandom` even though `toss'` already `runRVar` with `StdRandom`. It makes sense from a type perspective, but which `StdRandom` end up being used? If this question makes any sense at all.
3. Would it be possible to rewrite `foo`'s signature as `MonadRandom m => StateT Int m ()`

Comment: The type of `runRVar` is very general - in this case, the first `runRVar` is being instantiated at the type `RVar Bool -> StdRandom -> RVar Bool` when you use `toss'` inside of `foo` and `bar`. And this function is just the identity (or should be). In any case, StdRandom does not "do" anything - when you write `runRVar ... StdRandom` it simply means to use the `MonadRandom` interface as the source of randomness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. When monomorphism restriction is on (it's on by default), all types of top-level binders will be inferred monomorphic.
2. You should add `RVar` to the monad stack like you did in `bar`. `MonadRandom` is too general.
   `StdRandom` is just a data constructor, so it has no specific state. `random-fu` should handle updating state automatically.
3. Just add the signature. See 1.

Comment: I'm sorry just to clarify, you're saying by setting `NoMonomorphismRestriction`, I see now that I can write `bar :: MonadRandom m => StateT Int m ()`. *However* I should still write `StateT Int RVar ()` because `MonadRandom m` is too general? And you're saying `StdRandom` is just something to satisfy the typechecker, and does not actually initialize a random seed correct?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. By writing RVar you don't need to do runRVar *inside* StateT and can just provide a random generator from outside once. This also has the effect of making it easier to change the random number generator used (you just need to pass/edit it once instead of replacing all occurrences of StdRandom).